# Jee Advance 2022 Question

Tags: combinatorics

**Consider 4 boxes, where each box contains 3 red balls and 2 blue balls. Assume that all 20 balls are distinct. In how many different ways can 10 balls be chosen from these 4 boxes so that from each box at least one red ball and one blue ball are chosen?
A. 21816 B. 85536 C. 12096 D. 156816**

**My Approach:**

First, we select one red and one blue ball in 3×2 ways for one box.

For four boxes, number of ways for four boxes = 6^4 = 1296

From remaining 12 balls, we have to select 2 balls so that will be 12C2 = 66

So, total ways = 1296× 66 = 85536

Correct answer is 21816

What have I done wrong?

I just want to know my mistake as I know the correct method

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: To see why your approach overcounts, think about a smaller example: how many ways are there to choose 3 balls from one box so that at at least one red and one blue are chosen? Your approach counts $\{r_1,b_1,r_2\}$ as different from $\{r_2,b_1,r_1\}$.